# Why does the coroutine changes the value of a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity C#, I'm using a coroutine to display a simple pattern on the screen after x seconds using the line "yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f)" but after it's first called, it changes isPlayerTurn from false to true.

```
     void Update () {
        if (!isPlayerTurn) {
            pattern.Add (Random.Range (1, 5));
            Debug.Log (isPlayerTurn);
            StartCoroutine(ShowPattern());
            isPlayerTurn = true;

        }

        pointGUI.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = "Points: " + playerPoints;
    }

    private IEnumerator ShowPattern() {
        Debug.Log (isPlayerTurn);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.5f);
        Debug.Log (isPlayerTurn);

        // etc
    }
```

The output of the logs are

```
False
False
True
```

Is there a reason for this behavior or is it a logic error?

Comment: *It* doesn't change `isPlayerTurn`, *you* change `isPlayerTurn`. The code that changes it is right there in your question. Can you clarify by explaining what behaviour you were expecting and why?

Comment: @hvd The value of `isPlayerTurn` should still be `False` after that yield because it's necessary through the `ShowPattern()` function and should be `True` only after `ShowPattern()` finishes executing (on the //etc part).

Comment: I'm not asking why you want it to be `false`, I'm asking why you think the current code would keep it `false`.

Comment: Because I thought `isPlayerTurn = true;` would execute only after `ShowPattern()` finished.

Comment: Yes it executes after ShowPattern() finishes. You see two falses printed in side the ShowPattern. It still has false, it changes to true only ouside the function.

Comment: You can add some identifiers to your `Debug.Log` calls (something like `Debug.Log("Update " + isPlayerTurn)` so you know exactly which debug output is which.

Comment: do not use a coroutine.  Simply use ***Invoke*** to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hvd wrote you set isPlayerTurn to true.
When you start coroutine current method is not stopped, but it executes next statement in paralel to method in coroutine.

Here you cen see example how coroutine is working in unity: [The Unity3D StartCoroutine calls a function, when does that function return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855983/the-unity3d-startcoroutine-calls-a-function-when-does-that-function-return)